# Storing array of strings in specifies variables respectively

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm a beginner at JAVA and I'm writing this code that's supposed to receive an array of strings and store every string (array element) in the specified variables respectively. But it only stores the first element. Below is the code:

```
package ontoretrive;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

public class j {
static String sss= "male,O+,45,saudi,brain_diseases";
static int size =sss.length();

static String male="";
static String blood="";
static String age="";
static String nat="";
static String dis="";
static char temp;
static void func (){
    char[] charArray = sss.toCharArray();
    Character[] charObjectArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(charArray);
    int count=0;
    int x=0;
    while (x< size){
        temp =charObjectArray[x];
while(temp!=','&&count==0){
                male=male+temp;
                x++;
                temp =charObjectArray[x];}
x++;
temp =charObjectArray[x];

count++;            

while(temp!=','&&count==1){
        blood=blood+temp;
        x++;
        temp =charObjectArray[x];}
x++;
temp =charObjectArray[x];
count++;            

while(temp!=','&&count==2){
        age=age+temp;
        x++;
        temp =charObjectArray[x];
}x++;
temp =charObjectArray[x];
count++;            

while(temp!=','&&count==3){
        nat=nat+temp;
        x++;
        temp =charObjectArray[x];
}x++;
temp =charObjectArray[x];
count++;            


while(temp!=','&&count==4){
        dis=dis+temp;
        x++;
        //temp =charObjectArray[x];
        }
x++;
// temp =charObjectArray[x];
count++;    }

System.out.println(male);//end while1
System.out.println(blood);//end while1
System.out.println(age);//end while1
System.out.println(nat);//end while1
System.out.println(dis);//end while1

}//end func
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("dis1");
    func();
   System.out.println(male);//end while1

    //System.out.println("dis3");


}
}    //end class
```

Comment: Please indent your code for easy reading.

Comment: I think String.split(",") will make your life considerably easier

Comment: Actually you are stuck in an endless loop because you did comment out the `temp = `charObjectArray[x]` in the last loop (you´ll run into an `IOOBE` afterwards). Anyway, that´s a weird way to read through an array and i´d stick to what @BrianAgnew said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class j {

    static String sss = "male,O+,45,saudi,brain_diseases";
    static int size = sss.length();

    //I suggest you not to give them a start value or set them as null
    static String male = "";
    static String blood = "";
    static String age = "";
    static String nat = "";
    static String dis = "";

    static void func() {

        //it uses the "," character to breaks the string sss into pieces
        //so became into "male","O+","45","saudi","brain_diseases"
        String[] pieces = sss.split(",");

        //pieces[0] is the first piece so = "male"
        //pieces[1] is the second "O+" and so on
        male = pieces[0];
        blood = pieces[1];
        age = pieces[2];
        nat = pieces[3];
        dis = pieces[4];

        System.out.println(male);
        System.out.println(blood);
        System.out.println(age);
        System.out.println(nat);
        System.out.println(dis);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        func();        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to do what you're trying to do, using String's [split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method:

```
static void func (){
    String[] split = sss.split(",");
    if (split.length < 5) {
        // this means some error in the input, need to handle
    }  
    male=split[0];
    blood=split[1];
    age=split[2];
    nat=split[3];
    dis=split[4];
}
```